# Short reference on writing numbers and units

Tags: writing, writing-style, formatting, online-resource

What's a quick and useful reference, either in print or online, for writing numbers and reporting measurements in scientific texts? Something I could distribute to all new students, which would cover things they should be taught but do not always know, like:

- how to write big/small numbers in scientific form (1.78 10<sup>–12</sup>), including proper spacing?
- how to write units of measurement, in text and in abbreviated form? includes: when do you capitalize units, when do you pluralize them, etc.
- how to properly report significant figures, etc.
- when do you write variables in italics/roman/bold/underline?

Comment: "use http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx‌" is a good starting point.

Answer (score 5):

I guess [these recommendations](http://publish.aps.org/author-information) by the American Physical Society might be just what you are looking for. In particular, Style and Notation Guide for Physical Review/Physical Review Letters deals with scientific numbers, units, figures/tables, and use of roman/italic fonts. (For some strange reasons, it requires a secured connection to see the file; in case you couldn't see it, there is an excerpt [here](http://www.student.nada.kth.se/~f99-mle/Public/Blandat/howToWriteMath.pdf)).

Answer (score 4):

The [American Chemical Society](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch011) offers an online version of its *ACS Style Guide*. While this used to be available only in print, it is now apparently being distributed free of charge—or at least is available at any university with a subscription to ACS Journals. However, since it's intended to be a resource for anyone planning to submit to an ACS journal, I suspect it's generally available. The link above will take you to the specific chapter on math and units of measure.

Answer (score 1):

The SI unit brochure ([BIPM](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/)) is actually quite clear and well-written, and backs up many of its points with logical/physical justification. I would say the style guides (should) build on this.